# Problem with installing Code::Blocks on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, code-blocks

I was trying to install Code::Blocks on my PC. I just followed the official wiki,and then I encountered a problem just like below. What should I do next to solve these problems?

--Updates--

So sorry for not narrating clearly, the wiki is from Code::Blocks' official website:
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Code::Blocks_nightly_build_on_Ubuntu . The version of Code::Blocks in the Ubuntu Software Center is too old, that's why I didn't choose it.

I used the instructions from Code::Blocks' official website to install Code::Blocks successfully and it runs normally, but today when I clicked the Code::Blocks icon nothing happened, and that's why I tried to reinstall it.

```
yuyue@ThinkPad:~/Downloads/debian-stable/amd64$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
    dpkg-deb: error: `amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
    dpkg: error processing amd64.deb (--install):
     subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks.
    (Reading database ... 299683 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking codeblocks (from codeblocks_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-common 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-common_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-common ...
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-contrib.
    Unpacking codeblocks-contrib (from codeblocks-contrib_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-contrib-common 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-contrib-common_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-contrib-common ...
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-contrib-dbg.
    Unpacking codeblocks-contrib-dbg (from codeblocks-contrib-dbg_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package codeblocks-dbg.
    Unpacking codeblocks-dbg (from codeblocks-dbg_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-dev 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-dev ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-headers 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-headers_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-headers ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-libwxcontrib0_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev ...
    Preparing to replace codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers 13.12-1 (using codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers ...
    Preparing to replace libcodeblocks0 13.12-1 (using libcodeblocks0_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libcodeblocks0 ...
    Preparing to replace libwxsmithlib0 13.12-1 (using libwxsmithlib0_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libwxsmithlib0 ...
    Preparing to replace libwxsmithlib0-dev 13.12-1 (using libwxsmithlib0-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement libwxsmithlib0-dev ...
    Preparing to replace wxsmith-dev 13.12-1 (using wxsmith-dev_13.12-1_amd64.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement wxsmith-dev ...
    Preparing to replace wxsmith-headers 13.12-1 (using wxsmith-headers_13.12-1_all.deb) ...
    Unpacking replacement wxsmith-headers ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks:
     codeblocks depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
      Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up codeblocks-common (13.12-1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-contrib:
     codeblocks-contrib depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0); however:
      Version of libfontconfig1 on system is 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1.
     codeblocks-contrib depends on libgamin0; however:
      Package libgamin0 is not installed.
     codeblocks-contrib depends on codeblocks (= 13.12-1); however:
      Package codeblocks is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks-contrib (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up codeblocks-contrib-common (13.12-1) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-contrib-dbg:
     codeblocks-contrib-dbg depends on codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-1); however:
      Package codeblocks-contrib is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks-contrib-dbg (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of codeblocks-dbg:
     codeblocks-dbg depends on codeblocks (= 13.12-1); however:
      Package codeblocks is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing codeblocks-dbg (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up libcodeblocks0 (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up libwxsmithlib0 (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up wxsmith-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up wxsmith-headers (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up libwxsmithlib0-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-dev (13.12-1) ...
    Setting up codeblocks-headers (13.12-1) ...
    Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
    ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     amd64.deb
     codeblocks
     codeblocks-contrib
     codeblocks-contrib-dbg
     codeblocks-dbg
```

Comment: Codeblocks is in the software centre why not just install from there?  If you want to install from another source 'wiki' at least provide a link so we can see what steps you are following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`)
2. Type these commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pasgui/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install codeblocks
   ```

This should install 13.12 version.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have installed Code::Blocks successfully, but there seemed to be some else problem:I found that I can't build or run any files...
' Errors were encountered while processing:
 codeblocks
 codeblocks-contrib
 codeblocks-dbg
 codeblocks-contrib-dbg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
'

Comment: I don't have any problems, it works perfect for me. Maybe this is because of the things you did before installing from the ppa. Try to remove codeblocks and then reinstall it using the commands from above. To uninstall it you should do here `sudo apt-get purge codeblocks` . Also, try `man apt-get` if you're interested in learning more. Please reply and tell me how it works.

Comment: OMG, it looks like that I have broken the package system....

Comment: When I try to uninstall it like what you told me, the terminal tells me to try to apt-get -f install, and I did it, now it is downloading from the ppa...

Comment: So, does it work?